# Trouble Mounting Time Capsule SMB share: realpath No such file or directory

Tags: mount, smb

I'm trying to mount the share from my Time Capsule via CLI (it works fine via the Finder's connect window, but I need to do this remotely). Should be a simple operation:

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/test
$ mount -v -o automounted,soft -t smbfs smb://user:password@10.0.1.1/Folder /Volumes/test
mount_smbfs: mount error: /Volumes/test: No such file or directory
$ ls -ldh /Volumes/test 
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 nick 68 Jul 25 10:59 /Volumes/test
```

FWIW: I get the same error if I `sudo` the commands too. This is on macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

I've tried a bunch of different variations and keep hitting this issue. There's obviously a directory at my mount point and if I make up a directory it gives a different error?!

Comment: I don't know but I note that the man page for mount_smfs fives a different URL i.e. no smb:

Comment: Thanks @Mark but same error even without the `smb:` prefix.  Also same error without the `-o automounted,soft` args too.

Comment: perhaps the permissions on /Volumes/test are wring make it 777

Comment: @Mark unfortunately `777` permissions didn't make a difference either.

Comment: I have the same problem also on 10.11.6.